# Is there a "standard" method of breaking ties when rounding in the field of mathematics?

Tags: arithmetic, online-resources, rounding-error

I recently found that [software packages](https://github.com/julialang/julia/issues/8750#issue-46387044) deal with ties in different ways:

- round ties away from zero: `round(0.5) = 1.0`, `round(1.5) = 2.0`
- round ties to even: `round(0.5) = 0.0`, `round(1.5) = 2.0`

I am aware there [other methods as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_the_nearest_integer).

I am now looking for an **authoritave** source that supports one of these methods as being "standard" in mathematics. I found serveral online sources ([1](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/rounding-methods.html), [2](https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-round-numbers-2312079), [3](https://sciencenotes.org/rounding-numbers-rules-and-examples/)) that support the "away from zero" method as the "standard" but they don't seem to carry much authority.

Comment: There can be no authoritative way when it comes to implementation. Whichever way is the easiest or the most intuitive for your users wins. However, there is a standard "floor function" $\lfloor x \rfloor$ or "integer part" function $[x]$ both meaning "always round down" in maths, specifically $\max_{z \in \mathbb{Z}} \{z \le x\}$. The fact that it is increasing and bounded by $x$ is useful in some proofs, but it doesn't mean that it should be the standard in some software package.

Comment: There are those, and other, conventions. See: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_the_nearest_integer). In particular, those two are called "Round half away from zero" and "Round half to even" in the Wikipedia article. None of those conventions is an absolute standard. Few things are affected by the exact choice of the convention, although in math education if you apply a different convention from the one you've been taught, you can get marked down. :(

Comment: @StinkingBishop, sorry, I should've included the link to Wikipedia in my question as I saw it already. I was hoping there would be a single convention I could cite, but from what I gather from the comments so far there is no single source to cite.

Comment: There is not one universally agreed standard in the first place, that's the problem. (If it is a problem after all!)

Comment: Giving it a further thought why this issue is actually not *that* much important in pure mathematics at all: it is an artefact of human evolution that we have $10$ fingers and so we use the decimal number system. If, for example, we had $3$ fingers, the value $0.5$ would not even be representable in the (ternary) number system as a finite (ternary) number, so whatever value you would consider to be $(0.5)_{10}=(0.1111\ldots)_3$ *would always* be closer to either $0$ or to $1$.

Comment: Rounding is not an operation that is commonly used in (pure) mathematics, only in applications. That means that there has never been a need for a standard in mathematics. And applications typically use whatever is best in there area/case, which typically means that it should affect their calculations as little as possible.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity the origin form my question is that someone I discussed this with (a mathematician) was adamant that rounding ties away from zero was the standard in mathematics, but I couldn't find a source stating that as the standard, hence I posted the question here.